# Google Geomap API change region option onClick()

Tags: javascript, google-api, geomap

This piece of code draws a map with the [Google Geomap API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);
    function drawMap() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string','iso'); //e.g.: mx
        data.addColumn('number','population'); //e.g.: 114
        data.addRows([["mx",114],["ec",14],["ve",28]]);
        var options = {
            region: '005',
            width: '511px',
            height: '280px',
            showLegend: true
        };
        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(document.getElementById('map'));
        geomap.draw(data,options);
    };
</script>
```

The region that is selected by default is 005 (South America). These are other available regions:

- 013 - (Central America)
- 150 - (Europe)

How can I change the region of the already drawn map dinamically? Something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="changeRegion(150);">Europe</a>
```

I know that the map will have to be redrawn, but i'm kind of stuck in the region property modification step. Any ideas will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the data, I give you a snippet I use in my own app. Easier to understabd rather than long explanations I guess. Hope it helps. 
In my case, I wanted to display numbers by country in the same region.

```
geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(document.getElementById('geo_chart'));


        google.visualization.events.addListener( geomap, 'regionClick', 
            function(e) 
            { 
                var dataLocal = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                var grouped_cities;

                if (e['region'] == "0")
                    return;

                options['colors'] = [0xaacdf8, 0x164177]; //orange colors
                options['dataMode'] = 'markers';
                options['region'] = e['region'];
                options['showZoomOut'] = true;

                if ( previous_region !=  e['region'] )
                {
                    var indexes  = dataFull.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, value: e['region']}]);

                    dataLocal.addRows(indexes.length);
                    dataLocal.addColumn('string', 'City');
                    dataLocal.addColumn('number', 'Views');

                    for ( i=0; i<indexes.length; i++ )
                    {
                        dataLocal.setValue(i, 0, dataFull.getValue(indexes[i], 2));
                        dataLocal.setValue(i, 1, dataFull.getValue(indexes[i], 3));
                    }


                    grouped_cities = google.visualization.data.group( dataLocal, [0],[{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]);
                    previous_region =  e['region'];
                }

                geomap.draw(grouped_cities, options);
                delete grouped_cities;
                delete dataLocal;

            }
        );
```